# Error: GoModulesBuilder:Build - [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: go, build, aws-sam, goland

I am not able to test my lambda on local machine (goland).

Getting error

`Error: GoModulesBuilder:Build - [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid SAM Build has failed: Command did not exit successfully, exit code: 1`

project structure

```
<project>
|
\---cmd
    \---restlambda\
        \---.aws-sam
        |  main.go (lambda handler here)
        |  restlambda
        |  restlambda.zip
        |  template.yml
```

command goland executes

```
sam build <project> --template <project>\cmd\restlambda\template.yaml --build-dir <project>\cmd\restlambda\.aws-sam\build
```

template.yml

```
Properties:
  Handler: restlambda
  Runtime: go1.x
  CodeUri: ./restlambda.zip
```

But when I change template.yml to

```
Properties:
  Handler: main::LambdaHandler
  Runtime: go1.x
  CodeUri: ./
```

```
cannot find package "<project>\\cmd\\restlambda\\main::LambdaHandler" in any of:    C:\Program Files\Go\src\C:\Users\akshay.ware\PLG\sportal\selfServe\cmd\restlambda\main::LambdaHandler (from $GOROOT)    C:\Users\akshay.ware\go\src\C:\Users\akshay.ware\PLG\sportal\selfServe\cmd\restlambda\main::LambdaHandler (from $GOPATH)
```

Help

Edit : sam local start-api with the previous template.yml is working fine